# GIT uses file modification data instead of file contents

Tags: git

I am curious if git can check the actual file instead of file modification date/time. Git currently just checks the file modification time and even if the file contents are same, it shows as modified. Can we alter this behavior?

Comment: "it show as modified" in what context?

Comment: Just by looking at the file modification date/time, I thought. Lemme try what has been suggested by "phd"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git` certainly doesn't behave this way. It checks file modification date and if it's not changed `git` decides the file is not modified. But if modification date is changed `git` **does not decide the file is modified** — it checks content. See:

```
$ git init test-git
Initialized empty Git repository in tmp/test-git/.git/

$ cd test-git/

$ echo >test.txt

$ git add test.txt 

$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
[master (root-commit) c02d9aa] Initial commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 test.txt

$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ touch test.txt 

$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

`touch` changes the file timestamp but `git` still thinks the file is not changed because it checked the content and found it the same.